# Why PDO does not show any result?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I've used PDO in my PHP application. But I have problem with `fetch()` function. Whenever I count the result of `fetch()`, it tells me there is something in resultset. But when I want to show them, it has nothing to show.

```
try
{ 
    $sql = "SELECT id,salt FROM tbl_admin WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($username,$password));
    $rows = $q->columnCount();

    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        $r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        echo(count($r).'<br />'); // Prints 1
        print_r($r); // Nothing to print ...
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        die('error');
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

May you help me please?

Comment: Column count is not row count

Comment: Hey friends, rouwCount() is not my problem here. I have nothing to show after `fetch()`

Comment: How do you know there is something to fetch? You're not checking how many rows are returned.

Comment: @Leigh: in this particular case the `$rows > 0` is always true, as long as each result set has some amount of columns

Comment: Thank you friends. I found out the problem was in sent values through `$_POST`. They were wrong and it was right that I got any result. But the returned `count($r) = 1` made my problem.
Also I changed `columnCount()` to `rowCount()`.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi, you're checking if there's at least one result returned, so `columnCount()` is better than `rowCount()` you were doing it right. Maybe your variable name is confusing, that's all!

Comment: @Adnan now both of them are working. However I guess `columnCount()` is right too. Because it returns the quantity of returned columns of result set

Comment: @MohammadSaberi, read the description in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), it says that you shouldn't rely on the behavior of `rowCount()`

Comment: @Adnan `rowCount` is indeed mentioned in the specs as unreliable, but in my opinion it's the equivalent of the old `mysql_affected_rows` which also behaved like this and was designed (and named) according to this behavior: counting rows affected by INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE not rows SELECTED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're counting the number of columns, not the number of rows.

`$rows = $q->columnCount();`

This should be

`$rows = $q->rowCount();`

---

That said, `rowCount` is for UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE queries. So that isn't the problem here.

Firstly should also be checking if `$q->execute` returns true or false.

Secondly you should be checking if `$q->fetch` returns true or false.

Given your code

```
$r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
echo(count($r).'<br />'); // Prints 1
```

Try the following.

```
echo(count(false));
```

You'll notice that this also outputs 1.

So the solution is, that you need to check the return value of `$q->fetch` before assuming it returned a valid row.

Comment: That's not the issue, if there's a result then `columnCount()` would be greater than `0`. I use this kind of check all the time because `rowCount()` isn't reliable. Please refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for more on this issue.

Comment: @Adnan Is that better for you?